# Passando Parametros do HTML para o Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Boa tarde Galera!

Preciso passar parâmetros de um pequeno formulário HTML para uma função do Javascript mas já tentei de todas as formas e não funciona!

Onde estou errando?

```js
function pessoa(nome) {
  this.nome = nome;

}

var pessoa1 = new pessoa(document.getElementById('nome'));

function mostrar() {
  document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML = pessoa1.nome;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Qual é o seu nome? <input type="text" id="nome"><br><br>
  <button id="btn-enviar" onclick="mostrar()">ENVIAR</button>
</form>

<p id="texto"></p>
```

Comment: Talvez o evento `onsubmit` do form te ajude com essa tarefa. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp)

Answer (score 9):

Seu código tem muito erro estrutural.

Primeiro, nessa linha:

```
var pessoa1 = new pessoa(document.getElementById('nome'));
```

Você está atribuindo o elemento retornado por `getElementById` à propriedade  `nome`, da classe `pessoa`, e não o valor do elemento.

O correto seria `document.getElementById('nome').value`.

Mas aí tem outro problema: Se você quer atualizar o valor sempre que for clicado em `mostrar`, então você deveria fazer a criação da instância de `pessoa` quando `mostrar` fosse chamado.

Se definir isso fora da função, como você fez, o valor capturado seria apenas o que tivesse definido inicialmente.

Então, eu modifiquei seu código, deixei ele assim:

```html
<form>
    Qual é o seu nome? <input type="text" id="nome"><br><br>
    <button id="btn-enviar" onclick="mostrar(event)">ENVIAR</button>
</form>

<p id="texto">

</p>


<script type="text/javascript">

/**
 para classes, use letra maiúsculas
*/
function Pessoa(nome){
    this.nome = nome;
}

var pessoa1;

function mostrar(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    pessoa1 = new Pessoa(document.getElementById('nome').value);

    console.log(pessoa1);

    document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML = pessoa1.nome;
}

</script>
```

Note que além de tudo, tive que usar o `event.preventDefault()`, pois o `form` faria que um submit fosse enviado. `preventDefault()` previne a ação padrão do elemento.

## Dicas:

- Se vai usar apenas eventos Javascript, não tem necessidade de usar a tag `form`. Um formulário com um botão dentro, sem especificar o `type`, vai fazer o navegador entender que você quer submeter o formulário. Se você clicar nele, a página provavelmente seria atualizada. Por isso usei o `preventDefault` dentro do form, mas sem o `form` nem seria necessário.
- Evite usar `onclick` para chamar funções. Isso costuma deixar o código mais difícil de dar manutenção. Eu recomendaria a utilização de `addEventListener`.

Exemplo:

```
  function mostrar(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // resto do código
  }


  document.getElementById('nome').addEventListener('click', mostrar);
```

Veja uns exemplos [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener).

- Se `pessoa` é um objeto simples, porque não usar um `Object` do próprio Javascript?

Talvez, no seu caso, fosse necessário apenas fazer isso:

```
var pessoa = {nome: null}
```

No final, eu deixaria assim:

```js
var elTexto = document.querySelector('#texto');
var elNome = document.querySelector('#nome');

var pessoa = {nome: null};


document.querySelector('#botao').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   pessoa.nome = elNome.value;
   elTexto.innerHTML = elNome.value;

   console.log(pessoa);
})
```

```html
Qual é seu nome?
<input type="text" id="nome" />

<button id="botao">Enviar</button>

<p id="texto"></p>
```

Comment: Dê o feedback sobre o porque do negativo. É importante pra sabermos o que pode ser melhorado na resposta.

Comment: cara! Sensacional!

Não espera essa AULA!

Mas criei dessa forma pq estou estudando orientação ao objeto =D

Comment: Com a sua ajuda consegui entender o codigo e atualizei dessa forma:

 <script type="text/javascript">


 function Pessoa(nome){

     this.nome = nome;

 }

 function mostrar(){

     var pessoa1 = new Pessoa(document.getElementById('nome').value);

     document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML = pessoa1.nome;

 }

</script>

Answer (score 2):

Usando seu código eu adicionei um `name` ao `input` e no `onsubmit` eu coloquei uma chamada para a função `mostrar` utilizando o `call` passando o `this` como parâmetro dessa forma o `this` da função `mostrar` será o proprio `ObjectHTML form` e assim eu consigo acessar o `this.nome` graças ao `name` colocado no `input`. O `return false` no `onsubmit` server para ele não enviar o formulario.

```js
function mostrar(){
    alert(this.nome.value);
    document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML = this.nome.value;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="mostrar.call(this); return false;">
  Qual é o seu nome? <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"><br><br>
  <button id="btn-enviar">ENVIAR</button>
</form>

<p id="texto"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom no java script é o seguinte, você faz essa função que vai pegar o conteudo do html, com innerHtml você vai escrever no html.

```
<script>
  function getName(){
   var content = document.getElementById('texto');
   console.log(content); // Resultado será mostrado no console.
   alert(content); // Resultado será mostrado ao carregar a página
 }
</script>

<body>
<from method="post">
<input type="text" name="texto" id="texto"/><br/>
<input type="submit" onclick="getName()" value="Pegar Nome"/> <!-- Função do javascript no onClick após aperta o botão pega o nome digitado. -->
</form>
</body>
```

Depedendo da função pode por no body como onLoad.

Comment: Upvoted! Não entendi porque negativaram esta resposta, se está correta. Stack Overflow Português é desmotivador...